# toUpper() method causing input exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

I want the users of my program to be able to repeat an action until they instruct the program to stop running by entering a certain string. I'm trying to allow the user to stop a program by entering the word "stop" by using:

```
If (sequenceSelector.ToUpper().Contains("stop"))    
{
    //code to do stuff here
}
```

Currently the only place the variable `sequenceSelector` can be accessed is encapsulated in this try block.

```
try
{                    
    int sequenceSelector = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (sequenceSelector <=0)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
    String outputString = "[" + sequenceSelector.ToString() + "]: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sequenceSelector; i++)
    {
        outputString = outputString + fibonacciSequence.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(outputString);

    return sequenceSelector;
}
```

This causes a problem because one of the catch blocks related is:

```
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input detected! Please enter a number that is not <=0 and not > 20");
    return null;
}
```

This prevents the user from entering any non-numerical characters because `sequenceSelector` must be an `int` in order for the program to function correctly.

I want to be able to let the user enter the word "stop" as part of the program. How can I do this get around the exception handling in order to do this?

Comment: ToUpper makes strings uppercase. Comparing with a lowercase "stop" will not work.

Comment: I was under the impression that it converts the text to uppercase in order to make it case insensitive

Comment: @Harry a string itself is neither case-sensitive nor insenstive. The _comparison_ can be one of that, but not the string itself. `"stop".ToUpper()` _returns_ a new string `"STOP"`.

Comment: Ah, thank you @RenéVogt for the advice.

Comment: This question needs a better title. As it is, the question (title) really has nothing to do with the actual question (body). I just don't know what it should be

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 IMO, the title is relevant as the try/catch block is preventing some code that I wish to be in my program from functioning correctly. However, please feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: @Harry even if that's so, it certainly not something really "Google-able" and as it stands "in my code" is implied. Again, I am not sure of what might be appropriate, just throwing it out there for someone else.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I will have a think and if I can find something more appropriate as a title, I will amend accordingly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `sequenceSelector` a string and check if it is convertible to an `int` using [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string sequenceSelector = Console.ReadLine();
int intValue;
if(int.TryParse(sequenceSelector, out intValue))
{
    if (intValue <= 0)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
    String outputString = "[" + sequenceSelector + "]: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < intValue; i++)
    {
        outputString = outputString + fibonacciSequence.GetValue(i) + ", "; // you can omit the call to ToString, it´s called implictely by the runtime
    }
    Console.WriteLine(outputString);

    return intValue;
}
else if(sequenceSelector.ToUpper().Contains("STOP")) { ... }
```

Comment: Apologies, I neglected to mention that this code is inside a `private static int? CaptureInitialNumber` so this method comes back with the error `not all code paths return a value.`. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **first** check if "stop" is contained in the **string** returned by `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input.ToUpper().Contains("STOP"))
    return; // or do something to leave the loop

// now you now it's not "stop" -> parse it
int sequenceSelector = Convert.ToInt32(input);
```

`sequenceSelector.ToUpper()` won't work, because `sequenceSelector` is an `int`. And even if it does work, the result won't contain `"stop"` but `"STOP"`.